# Is it safe to login to google account through a third party's app domain

Tags: android, google-oauth

Something I've noticed recently with some android apps is that when I try to login using my google account I get redirected to a login page, but that login page is wrapped inside of the app's domain.

As a made up example say I'm trying to login to SomeRestaurantChain's android app, and I choose to login using my google account. Usually I get redirected to a google login and it shows that I'm already logged in, and I just select my account and approve the login with Google. Instead, with SomeRestaurantChain's app, I'm getting redirected to a login page, and it shows that I'm not logged into my google account, and prompts for user name and password. I go to my password manager, and it's asking me if I want to add a login for com.SomeRestaurantChain.something, so it looks like they are trying to have me login to my google account, but wrapped inside of a page that is hosted through their domain.

I feel like this is not how this should be handled, and even though I don't think they are intentionally trying to do something nefarious, on principle I refuse to put in my credentials for google unless it is through a domain owned by google, but I've seen this happen with at least two of my apps now that I used to be logged into just fine before.

Has something changed with OAuth protocols that are forcing these app developers to do this? Or is this safe and standard practice and I'm just overly spooked by it? I contacted their support email, but their response was of no help.

EDIT:
I was originally trying to keep the app anonymous, but I don't think it will matter much and it will help anyone else seeing this in trying to reproduce what I'm seeing. It's the Carl's Jr app, and the domain that is wrapping the login to google is com.carlsjr.ordering

Comment: 3rd party domains should not ever see credentials, that's the reason oauth exists, give scoped authorization to your data  / account without giving them your account. If it happens to your apps, have you fallen victim to some malicious component maybe?

Comment: @zapl the domain listed definitely belongs to the app, it's not some kind of man in the middle malware

Comment: Do not use this app.  It is at best completely oblivious to security practices, at worst active malware.

Comment: `com.carlsjr.ordering` is not a valid internet domain, it looks like a package name to me, i.e. some app component. I'd suspect what you see is some login component of the app. It could be fine, it really depends on what's happening here. It's usually not obvious when a task in android switches to a different app for login for example. The app isn't available at my location (Europe) so I can't have a closer look. https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/credential-manager is what integration into Android should probably look like, at least in native apps

Comment: Have you checked that the login dialog is not an iframe in the restaurant web page? AFAIR modern web browser can separate iframe content from the outer frame if the iframe is configured that way.

Comment: To clarify, this is in an android app, and not in a browser, so com.carlsjr.ordering is the android package, but with my password manager on my phone when logging in through an app it is associated with that package domain. I'm not that familiar with app development, but AFAIK if it shows com.carlsjr.ordering that means my login is being entered into that app, and maybe they are running an iframe, but it still seems weird that my user name and password would be passing through the app at all.